# Spring Boot + React Login not working

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

When adding spring-boot-starter-security to my gradle file and adding a WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor override to use my React login component, I never can get to my React login form, I get a generic one prompted by the browser ...  if I log into the generic box, then navigate to localhost/login, I can see my React logon component.  Why can't I get it to use my React one as the actual login prompt/page/box???

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login", "/index.html", "/index.min.js").permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
    .and().logout()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
}
```

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: is 9001 your port number for your spring boot application ??

Comment: how did you manage to set up link between spring-boot and reactjs?

Comment: @Automator1992 - Yes 9001 is my port ...

Comment: @Vikram - I took the build files from my webpack output and temporarily moved them into my src/main/resources folder ...

Comment: I think its just an issue with spring atm, I cant even get spring boots out of the box login page when using .formLogin()

Comment: @MatthewStruensee try disabling the default security of the spring boot by setting the security.basic.enabled=false in the applications.properties file.

Comment: It was mis configuration with the Spring Boot application.  It was not even using my class.  Once it was using it, it did get it to load the login which lead to other issues for me to try and figure out :)...